# H3 tag doesn't update with hidden field value with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, forms

Below is the code i am working with. Currently it all works pretty well when you choose the child quantity from a dropdown. So far it calculates how much it should be and then updates a hidden field on change; works fine.

What i wanted to do was outside this function, update a h3 tag with the value of the hidden field but i keep getting the value of 0, which is the default value. Purpose of this is that i need to display the absolute total of adults, children and oap's before the form is submitted so customers know how much they will be charged.

HTML:

```
<select name="16a. Bronze Tour Package - Children £28" class="smalldropdown">
    <option selected="selected">Children £28</option>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
    <option>4</option>
    <option>5</option>
    <option>6</option>
    <option>7</option>
    <option>8</option>
    <option>9</option>
    <option>10</option>
</select>
<p id="bronzeChildTotalView">Child total is: £0</p>
<form>
    <input type="hidden" id="bronzeChildTotal" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="bronzeAdultTotal" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="bronzeOAPsTotal" value="0">
</form>
<h3 id="bronzeGrandTotal" class="h3margin">
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var bronzeChild = $('select[name="16a. Bronze Tour Package - Children £28"]'),
        bronzeAdult = $('select[name="16b. Bronze Tour Package - Adults £35"]'),
        bronzeOAPs = $('select[name="16c. Bronze Tour Package - OAPs £28"]');

    bronzeChild.on('change', function () {
        var value = $(this).val();
        var result = $('#bronzeChildTotal');
        var resultView = $('#bronzeChildTotalView');
        if (bronzeChild[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
            alert('Choice cannot be ' + value + ' please choose a number of children');
        }
        var total = value * 28;
        var plural = '';
        if (value == 1) {
            plural = 'child';
        } else {
            plural = 'children';
        }

        if (isNaN(total)) {
            result.val(0);
            total = 0;
        } else {
            result.val(total);
            resultView.text('Child total is: £'+total);
        }
        resultView.text('Child total is: £'+total);
    });
    // This is the h3 tag that needs updating
    $('#bronzeGrandTotal').text($('#bronzeChildTotal').val());
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update the `h3` text within the `change` event handler.

> problem is there will be more than one, there will be adults and oaps aswell. Will i have to run this inside each function to update the total?

To cater for this you should separate out the `h3` updating logic, so you can call it from the `change` handler for all three `select` elements. Try this:

```
bronzeChild.on('change', function () {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var result = $('#bronzeChildTotal');
    var resultView = $('#bronzeChildTotalView');
    if (bronzeChild[0].selectedIndex == 0) {
        alert('Choice cannot be ' + value + ' please choose a number of children');
    }
    var total = value * 28;
    var plural = '';
    if (value == 1) {
        plural = 'child';
    } else {
        plural = 'children';
    }

    if (isNaN(total)) {
        result.val(0);
        total = 0;
    } else {
        result.val(total);
        resultView.text('Child total is: £'+total);
    }
    resultView.text('Child total is: £'+total);


    // This is the h3 tag that needs updating
    updateGrandTotal();
});

var updateGrandTotal = function() {
    var childTotal = $('#bronzeChildTotal').val() || 0;
    var adultTotal = $('#bronzeAdultTotal').val() || 0;
    var oapTotal = $('#bronzeOAPsTotal').val() || 0;
    $('#bronzeGrandTotal').text(+childTotal + +adultTotal + +oapTotal);
};
```

Comment: problem is there will be more than one, there will be adults and oaps aswell. Will i have to run this inside each function to update the total?

Comment: Sorry if that sounds like a basic question haha. Just wasn't sure if that would cause any issues

Comment: In that case you need to amend your code to add up a total based on all three selects - not just the child - and update the `h3` after that calculation.

Comment: If i update my code, can i show you exactly what im working with? Most variables are called within the functions so was sure that wouldn't work. 2 mins